# Linq filtering/search logic

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

I have Building entity which has Apartments field. I want to filter only those buildings which have at least one apartment fulfilling search model.

Request search model JSON:

```
{ 
   ........

  "numberOfRooms": null, 
  "isStudio": true, 
  "isNoPlanning": true, 
  "isMultiRoom": true, 

   ......
}
```

This is my filter logic

```
IEnumerable<Building> buildings = buildingApiDTO.Where(numberOfRooms => (searchModel.NumberOfRooms == null || numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(roomsCount => searchModel.NumberOfRooms.Contains(roomsCount.RoomsCount.ToString())))
                || (searchModel.IsStudio == false || (searchModel.IsStudio == true && numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(isStudio => isStudio.IsStudio)))
                || (searchModel.IsNoPlanning == false || (searchModel.IsNoPlanning == true && numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(isNoPlanning => isNoPlanning.IsFreePlaning)))
                || (searchModel.IsMultiRoom == false || (searchModel.IsMultiRoom == true && numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(multiRoom => multiRoom.RoomsCount >= 4))))
```

These are my entities.

```
public class Building 
{
  .....

  public ICollection<Apartment> Apartments {get;set;}

  .....
}
```

This is my apartment class.

```
public class Apartment 
    {
    public bool IsStudio {get;set;}

    public bool IsFreePlaning {get;set;}

    public bool IsMultiRoom {get;set;}

    public int Roomscount {get;set;}
}
```

Overall my filter logic does not work properly. I also got buildings which do not have a studio or no planing apartments. How can I filter only buildings which have only a studio or multiroom or free planing apartments?

Comment: Linq Filter should use like this. IEnumerable.Where( x => x.Variable == State )

Comment: I'm not sure if it's about predicate builder, (adding some of the filter with condition). Or debugging part of the filter?

Comment: have you tried to convert the query into a loop with if conditions? it is sometimes helpfull to figure out where the problem is. usually a false use of `||` where a `&&` should be standing

Answer (score 0):

this is from my understanding. try building the query per condition

```
var query = buildingApidDto.AsQueryable();

// check if search has number of rooms
if (searchModel.NumberOfRooms != null) 
{
   query = query.Where(numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(roomsCount => searchModel.NumberOfRooms.Contains(roomsCount.RoomsCount.ToString())))
}

//check if search is studio
if (searchModel.IsStudio)
{
    query = query.Where(numberOfRooms => numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(isStudio => isStudio.IsStudio)))
}
else
{
    query = query.Where(numberOfRooms => numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(isStudio => !isStudio.IsStudio)))
}

//check if search is no planning
if (searchModel.IsNoPlanning)
{
    query = query.Where(numberOfRooms => numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(isNoPlanning => isNoPlanning.IsFreePlaning)))
}
else
{
    query = query.Where(numberOfRooms => numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(isNoPlanning => !isNoPlanning.IsFreePlaning)))
}

//check if search is multi room
if (searchModel.IsMultiRoom)
{
    query = query.Where(numberOfRooms => numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(multiRoom => multiRoom.RoomsCount >= 4))))
}
else
{
     //just adding the opposite
     query = query.Where(numberOfRooms => 
   numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(multiRoom => multiRoom.RoomsCount < 4))))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, for each case, you need to check that it is studio/multiroom/no planning, **and also** that it is *not* the other 2.

```
IEnumerable<Building> buildings = buildingApiDTO.Where(numberOfRooms => (searchModel.NumberOfRooms == null || numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(roomsCount => searchModel.NumberOfRooms.Contains(roomsCount.RoomsCount.ToString())))
    || (
        searchModel.IsStudio && 
        numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(isStudio => isStudio.IsStudio) &&
        !searchModel.IsNoPlanning && 
        !searchModel.IsMultiRoom
        )
    || (
        searchModel.IsNoPlanning && 
        numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(isNoPlanning => isNoPlanning.IsFreePlaning) && 
        !searchModel.IsStudio && 
        !searchModel.IsMultiRoom
        )
    || (
        searchModel.IsMultiRoom && 
        numberOfRooms.Appartments.Any(multiRoom => multiRoom.RoomsCount >= 4) && 
        !searchModel.IsStudio && 
        !searchModel.IsNoPlanning
        )
    )
```